# Not able to git Pull from CMD after using JGIT to clone repo..getting SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, clone, git-pull, jgit

I used JGIT to clone a repo from bitbucket using HTTPS method which worked fine.
But I am trying to do is do a git pull from command Line from the cloned repo. When this is done i am getting *fatal: unable to access 'https://cedt-icg-bitbucket.**********.git/': SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain*

I don't want to use the suggested *git -c http.sslVerify=false* to solve as its not safe as its a private repo.
Any suggestions? please